# Strange output when echoing variable from a different user

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, colors

```
$ sudo su - user1 -c 'echo $DOMAIN_HOME'
/app/user1/DOMAINHOME
```

This looks fine, right? However, let's dig a little deeper:

```
$ sudo su - user1 -c 'echo $DOMAIN_HOME' | tee test.out
$less test.out

ESC]P0000000ESC]P8A9A9A9ESC]P1DC143CESC]P9FF0000ESC]P2008000ESC]PA00FF00ESC]P3aa9943ESC]PBFFD700ESC]P41E90FFESC]PC87CEFAESC]P5706c9aESC]PD826ab1ESC]P6FFA500ESC]PEF0F8FFESC]P7FFFFFFESC]PFFFFFFFESC[HESC[2JESC[HESC[2J/app/user1/DOMAINHOME
```

This is causing my scripts to fail.

They are color codes that are sourced by .bashrc which is sourcing colors for xterm. After doing a little research, the last section **[HESC[2JESC[HESC[2J** is what clears the terminal prior to outputting the path.

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why these are showing up. Any Ideas?

Note: When logged in as user1, it echoes the variable just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using "su -" the shell being executed is pretending like it's a login shell (executing the system's `/etc/profile`, the user's profile, such as `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, and so on).  One of those scripts is generating the escape sequence (the `Esc]P` string) and printing that result to stdout.  It shouldn't do that.

What it should be doing is checking to see if the shell is interactive, and *then* -- and only then! -- it should generate the escape sequence.

The best way to check for an interactive shell is to check the value of "$-" and see if it contains the letter `i` -- if it does, the shell is interactive, and if it doesn't, the shell is not.  I typically use something like this:

```
case "$-" in
*i*)  # Here if the shell is interactive
      ;;
*)    # Here otherwise
      ;;
esac
```

You'll need to determine what is generating that escape sequence.  Common culprits are `echo`, `tput`, and and other commands that are supposed to modify the terminal's settings.  I did some Google'ing but can't find that particular escape sequence, so I can't provide any clues as to where/what to look for.

Of course, why are you using `su -` at all?  Just use `sudo -u user1` and eliminate an extra step (your requirements might include executing `user1`'s .profile though; I don't know and you didn't say).

Comment: I tried the case statement in its own script while logged in as user1 and the shell doesnt show to be interactive. I tried it on a few other users and got the same result.

Comment: I've read over this a few times and am having a trouble understanding. The - executes the users .profile. So the users .profile isnt checking if stdin is a terminal? Should the terminal be interactive or noninteractive? And what would the solution be?

Comment: I've tried to clarify my answer better. :)

Comment: Thankyou :)  There are variables being referenced in the user's .profile as a part of the script, so I do need to use "su -". However, I did make some progress by finding the culprit. There is another file sourced in the .profile that is setting the terminal colors to a more readible format. I commented it out and the only esc sequence left (that was still poping up) was the clearing of the terminal when .bash_logout is executed on exit.

Comment: I think removing the custom terminal colors and clearing the .bash_logout would only band-aid the problem. It looks like all of my user sessions are non-interactive. I'm still learning and am unfamiliar with the differences between interactive and non-interactive. I'll research it now, but could that be the problem?

Comment: You said, "It looks like all of my user sessions are non-interactive", but I'm not sure what you mean by that.  If you use "su - -c" then the command that is executed will be run in a non-interactive shell (obviously, since the commands come from the command line, not a terminal session).  Perhaps you should take a different tack?  How about this: `sudo bash -c '. ~/.profile >/dev/null 2>&1; echo "$DOMAIN_HOME"' | tee test.out` ??  Or another option:  `sudo bash -c 'echo "<<<$DOMAIN_HOME>>>"' | sed -ne 's/.*<<<\(.*\)>>>.*/\1/p'` ??  It's ugly and I'd prefer to find and fix the real problem...